# Another proof of uniqueness of identity element of addition of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, proof-verification, learning

Please rate and comment. I want to improve; constructive criticism is highly appreciated.
Please take style into account as well.

The following proof is solely based on vector space axioms.
Axiom names are *italicised*.
They are defined in Wikipedia (vector space).

### Another proof of uniqueness of identity element of addition of vector space

We prove the uniqueness of an identity element of addition of a vector space.

Let $V$ be a vector space.
It remains to prove that an identity element of addition of $V$ is unique.
We define a predicate $P$ over $V$ as follows.
For every $v \in V$,
$$P(v) \quad := \quad \big(\, u + v = u \; \text{ for all } u \in V \,\big).$$

By *Identity element of addition*,
there exists an element of $V$ for which $P$ holds.
Let $0  \in V$ such that $P(0 )$ holds;
let $0' \in V$ such that $P(0')$ holds.
It remains to prove that $0 = 0'$.
\begin{align*}
 0 & = 0 + 0' && \text{since } P(0') \text{ holds.} \\
   & = 0' + 0 && \text{by }\textit{Commutativity of addition.}\ \\
   & = 0'     && \text{since } P(0) \text{ holds.}
\end{align*}
QED

P.S.: This is intended to improve [my previous, roundabout proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/891289/138360).
Of course, I could only incorporate a small subset of the helpful advice given there.

Comment: It's not wrong per se, but I found it odd that the phrase 'it remains to prove...' is at the beginning of the proof. It may also be a good idea to clearly state that your choice of $0,0'$ were arbitrary, but that is probably not necessary.

Comment: This is not new. The equation $0=0+0'=0'$ is in every book on algebra. The same works for uniqueness of identity in groups. Moreover, the predicate-introduction is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @fixedp: What wording would you use to state that they are arbitrary?