# Vector spaces - If an addend adds nothing, then the addend is the zero vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, proof-verification, learning

Please rate and comment. I want to improve; constructive criticism is highly appreciated.
Please take style into account as well.

With one exception, the following proof is solely based on vector space axioms.
Axiom names are *italicised*.
They are defined in Wikipedia (vector space).

### Vector spaces - If an addend adds nothing, then the addend is the zero vector.

Let $V$ be a vector space.
By [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/891871/138360), we know that a zero vector of $V$ is unique;
let $0$ be the zero vector of $V$.
Let $v_1, v_2 \in V$.

**If $v_1 + v_2 = v_1$, then $v_2 = 0$.**

*Proof.*
We assume that $v_1 + v_2 = v_1$.
It remains to prove that $v_2 = 0$.
Let $(-v_1)$ be an additive inverse of $v_1$.
\begin{align*}
0 &= v_1 + (-v_1)         && \text{by }\textit{Inverse elements of addition} \\
  &= (v_1 + v_2) + (-v_1) && \text{by assumption} \\
  &= (v_2 + v_1) + (-v_1) && \text{by }\textit{Commutativity of addition} \\
  &= v_2 + (v_1 + (-v_1)) && \text{by }\textit{Associativity of addition} \\
  &= v_2 + 0              && \text{by }\textit{Inverse elements of addition} \\
  &= v_2                  && \text{by }\textit{Identity element of addition} \\
\end{align*}
QED

Comment: Looks like a great proof to me.  I especially like that you justified each step.

Comment: The proof is absolutely correct. To avoid the use of the axiom of Commutativity of addition, you can add $-v_1$ to the left.

Comment: @Taladris In Wikipedia, the axiom of Inverse elements of addition only stated that $0 = v_1 + (-v_1)$, not that $0 = (-v_1) + v_1$. If that were stated, I could see how to improve the proof. Currently, I don't see how I could do it.

Comment: @dracomalfoy: OK. A vector space is a commutative group by definition, so it follows directly that $(-v_1)+v_1=0$. Actually, many books would state the axiom of existence of an additive inverse as $\forall v\in V,\ \exists w\in V;\ v+w=w+v=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is correct. More intuitively, the proof is by cancelling $\,v_1$ from both sides, by adding its inverse, which makes it clear that the proof  generalizes to the following *cancellation law*

$$ v+ u = v + w\ \Rightarrow\ u = w $$

This simple inference, that invertible elements are cancellable, is ubiquitous in algebra.