# How is this proof correct (takes $a$ to be a specific number)?

Tags: field-theory, proof-explanation

This is my professor's proof of uniqueness of additive identity:

assume there exists $0', 0 \in F$ where $a + 0 = 0 + a = a$ and $a + 0' = 0' + a = a$.

w.t.s that $0 = 0'$

taking $a = 0'$ and $a = 0$ we get $0 + 0' = 0'$ and $0 + 0' = 0$, therefore $0 = 0'$.

Why is she allowed to simply take $a = 0$ and $a = 0'$? Don't we want to show it for every $a$? This is what I don't get about *this* specific proof.

Comment: You've just shown that $0=0'$. That's all you set out to show. You're done.

Comment: I understand. My question was the last sentence. *Why* does this work? Why can you take $a = 0$ and $a = 0'$? Don't you want to show it for every $a$? @Oxonon

Comment: The zero element property holds for all $a$. So you picked one specific $a$, and that let you show $0=0'$.

Comment: But just because it holds for that $a$, how do you know it holds for all $a$? @Oxonon . You're just proving it for that specific $a$.

Comment: You don't want to *show* it for *any* $a$, much less for every $a$. You're assuming that $0$ and $0'$ are both additive identities, and what you want to show is that $0=0'$. Since they're both identities, you already *have* that $a+0=0+a=a$ for every $a$ and that $a+0'=0'+a=a$ for every $a$. Since you have this for every $a$, you also have it for any particular $a$, but you don't have to use all of them; you can pick whatever you want. That's because you're not showing this part; you already have it and you're *using* it instead.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I can maybe provide a "filled out" version of the proof with more details.

Assume there exists $0',0\in F$. By definition of identity, we know that $\forall a$, we have $a+0=0+a=a$ and $a+0'=0'+a=a$. Since these 2 equations are true for any $a$, they are true when $a=0$ and when $a=0'$ specifically. Substituting the 2 specific values of $a$ into the equations above, we will have 4 true equations:

1. $0+0=a=0$
2. $0+0'=0'+0=a=0$ (when $a=0$),
3. $0'+0=0+0'=a=0'$
4. $0'+0'=a=0'$ (when $a=0'$).

Out of the 4 true equations, 2 and 3 are the ones we need. We see that $0+0'=0$ and $0+0'=0'$. Combining the 2 equations, we get $0=0'$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: My question is not a duplicate. I am not asking about how to concoct a proof, or if it's a good proof. I'm asking why the step where you choose $a = 0$ and $a = 0'$ is mathematically and logically sound. @BillDubuque

Comment: @user129393192 That is explained (implicitly) in the linked answers,  viz. the hypotheses are *identities* i.e. they are assumed to hold true for *all* $\,a.\ $ Please review the *definition* of an *additive identity element*.

Comment: Yes. I understand they hold for all $a$, but I still don't fully understand why picking an $a$ and showing some other conclusion off it makes that conclusion true @BillDubuque, that is my question, and it's still unclear, and not answered.

Comment: @user129393192 We are assuming by hypothesis that  $\,\forall x\in F\!:\ x+0 = x = 0+x\,$ is true. This implies that $\,a+0 = a = 0+a\,$ is true for every element $\,a\in F,\,$ in particular it is true for  $\,a = 0'.\ \ $

Comment: So since it's true for $a = 0'$, when plug it in, we must have true statement? @BillDubuque either way, this is my fundamental question. it is more about the logic of when you "choose" to have the particular case, less than the additive identity proof.

Comment: @user129393192 A question about that inference rule  ([universal instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation)) would also be a dupe.

Comment: I do not see the duplicate, and I still do not understand the premise and how we can deduce our final conclusion from just $a = 0'$. @BillDubuque

Comment: Which step do you not understand in [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/891297/242) in the dupe?

Comment: that is not a dupe. this question is not about the *additive inverse* but about the logic of the assumption for $a = 0'$. I appreciate your fight against duplication, but I believe you go a bit far, especially when the questions are clear-cut different. An *implied* answer in another post is vague, and a new question, should have a **direct** answer, not a mere implication in another, separate question.